# What are the differences between mapping,binding and parsing?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, java-ee-6, jax-rs

I am starting to learn web-services in java EE6.

I did web development before, but never nothing related to web services.

All is new to me and the books and the tutorials i find in the web are to technical.

I started learning about .xsd schemas and also .xml.

In that topic i feel confident, i understand what are the schemas used for and what validation means.

Now my next step is learning about JAX-B(Java Api for XML Binding). I rode some about it and i did also some practice in my IDE. But i have lots of basic doubts, that make me stuck and cannot feel confident to continue to the next topic.

Ill appreciate a lot if someone could explain me well my doubts:

1. What does it mean mapping and what is a mapping tool?
2. What does it mean binding and what is a binding tool?
3. What does it mean parsing and what is a parsing tool?
4. How is JAX-B related to mapping,binding and parsing?

**I am seeking for a good answer built by you, not just a copy paste from google(Ive already been online a few hours and only got confused).**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on what I understand..

> What does it mean mapping and what is a mapping tool?

In case of Java/XML, mapping is nothing but representing a Java object model
in to an XML document representation ( and  vice versa. )
A mapping tool will allow you to convert from one format to another. This is just the definition step.

> What does it mean binding and what is a binding tool?

Binding is the process of in-memory(as the application is running) conversion of XML document to object represantation.
Binding is achieved through unmarshalling.

> What does it mean parsing and what is a parsing tool?

Parsing is reading an input stream of data and checking whether if the stream of data  coforms to certain grammar. Parsing tools consume stream of data and generate errors when the data fails to conforms to grammar that the tool is checking. It would also generate events to indicate that it has received certain "tokens" from the stream. In java/xml scenario, there are multiple types of parsers such as DOM, StAx, SAX...

> How is JAX-B related to mapping,binding and parsing?

JAXB mapping:

is when you use xjc to generate java class hierachy based on an XSD
The mapping occurs when classes are generated with JAXB annotations
Mapping tool in the scenario is xjc

JAXB Binding :

Occurs when an application unmarshalls an XML document to Object represanation 
`(JAXBElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal(
                    new File("some.xml"));`

Parsing :

in order to convert XML document to object represantation, the JAXB engine has to 
first "parse" the xml document to ensure correctness and then tokenize to instatiate java objects. This happens internally and you do not control ito ensure correctness and then tokenize to instatiate java objects.

Comment: This answer is good. But still have one doubt. What do you mean by in-memory conversion when talking about binding?

Comment: That means the conversion occurs in the memory while the application is running.

Comment: I understand better, but a new doubt just came :)
So binding actually is the process of marshaling and unparshaling at runtime right? What about mapping occurs at compile time? Or mapping is just the same as binding, it is just a process that inside itself contains a binding sub process?

Comment: No; mapping - is just the definition step no real XML document is involved except for the XSD(grammar). Binding(marshall/unmarshall) is the real execution step.

Comment: Ok i think now i really got it. So first through mapping we create some classes from the .XSD(That is the new feature mentioned that has JAXB). Then for binding we create some objects out of the classes we created before and perform marsaling/unmarsaling.
In all this thing lets say that some JAXB parser works behind the scene to allow reading the .xsd when mapping. Am i right? :)

Comment: I guess these pictures can support @ringbearer answer: [oracle image](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13758/img/jaxb.gif) and [class diagram](http://java.boot.by/wsd-guide/images/jaxb.gif)

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza This second image i have it in my book. After reading the answer and the comment i can now understand this diagram.

Comment: @sfrj - You can generate an XML model from an XML schema, but with JAXB you can also start with your own domain model and use annotations to customize the XML representation:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

Comment: @Blaise Doughan Yeah i know that is possible too. Thanks for reminding, but this time i wanted to understand the process that also includes the schema, because i rode somewhere that is a new feature in JAXB 2.0

Comment: @sfrj - Herwa is an example:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html?m=0

Comment: Thank you guys for clearing my doubts, specially to ring bearer for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would strongly suggest that you get a copy of [Java Web Services Up and Running](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652112X) and start at chapter 1 and start from there.  It is not easy or intuitive, get ready for a long learning curve.  Note. All the binding stuff will just confuse you unless you have a basic understanding of how all the pieces work.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation. But currently i am reading this one: http://www.amazon.com/RESTful-Java-Jax-RS-Animal-Guide/dp/0596158041/ref=tmm_pap_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=1294995588&sr=8-2